# SELECTED_REAL_KIND in C

Tags: c, fortran

Is there any equivalent of [SELECTED_REAL_KIND](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND.html) (in Fortran) in C language ?

Comment: @Olaf, I just wanted to know if is there any predifined function that i can use directly before i start coding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECTED_REAL_KIND` is a standard Fortran mechanism for choosing at build time a real data type that meets or exceeds specified parameters for numeric representation.  In particular, it is used to select a data type by precision and / or exponent range and / or radix.

Standard C does not have a built-in parameterized facility such as that for designating data types.  It *does* have standard macros whose values describe the properties of the implementations of the standard floating-point types, `float`, `double`, and `long double`.  Their joint radix, their precisions in both decimal digits and implementation-radix digits, and their minimum and maximum exponent values (also in both decimal and implementation-radix forms) are all available via these macros.  These are defined in the standard header [`float.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/float.h.html).  (The link is to POSIX, which is formally aligned with the C standard here.)

It is possible to use the C preprocessor conditionals and these macros to define macros or typedefs for types that meet your specific requirements, which you can then use throughout your code.  This is not as tidy as Fortran's approach, but it gets the job done.

Comment: "there is no official, directly-linkable version of this section of the C standard itself" ... maybe this can substitute the standard itself: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2

Comment: The final draft (n1570) is identical to the standard in all relevant aspects (there were just to minor changes for two predefined macros, both tagged accordingly in the draft to be replaced by the final value). So, there is very well a linkable version. Once the link @pmg provided (inofficially) or a pdf version from the IEEE.

Comment: I have altered my wording to deflect focus from why I chose the particular web source for `float.h` that I did.